# Chrome Extension - Context Menu On Specific Pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am wondering if it is possible to show the following context menu item only if it is on specific pages.

I think it has something to do with **documentUrlPatterns** (Which can be seen [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#property-createProperties-documentUrlPatterns) as of typing this) but I am not sure how to implement it with the following code:

---

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "App Name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Description",

    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs"
     ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["script.js"]
    }
}
```

---

script.js

```
function getword(info,tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ 
        url: "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + info.selectionText,
    })
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({

    title: "Search: %s", 
    contexts:["selection"], 
    onclick: getword,

});
```

---

It would be great if you could provide a demo which will only work on specific sites of your choice (For instance, any directory of Stack Overflow and any directory of Google).

PS. The above code allows users to make a selection on any site and provides a button (In the context menu) which will search for what the user has selected on http://www.google.com/search?q= {Selection}

Comment: You are on right track here. You need to provide an array of url patterns  as documentUrlPatterns for which you want to enable the context menu option exactly like what you have done for title, contexts and onclick. 
BTW the exact utility is already present in Chrome browser.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have stripped down your code to demonstrate selective context menu option display.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "zambrey",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Description",

    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
     ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["trial.js"]
    }
}
```

trial.js

```
var showForPages = ["https://www.google.com/","*://github.com/zambrey/*","http://www.nytimes.com/"];

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "zambrey",
    "documentUrlPatterns":showForPages
});
```

Be sure to check out http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html for more details on url pattern syntax.

Also refer to this http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/basic.zip sample for more complex context menus.

Comment: Yes! I knew it! It did have something to do with the property "documentUrlPatterns"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the "permissions" option in the manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://stackoverflow.com/*"
]
```

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question.

Comment: I believe Zambrey is correct, you misunderstood the question.
I tried to have the following under permissions:
"contextMenus",
"http://stackoverflow.com//*"

but it still works on each site. Anyways, thanks for attempting to help me but this will still remain an open question.

Comment: @JC did you find answer on this question? It seems documentUrlPatterns no works for web pages.

Comment: @abg Yes, an answer has already been selected as correct (answer by zambrey). If you have a question, I believe you should ask a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask